# Conditional CSS depending on OS

Tags: css, fonts, conditional-comments

I know there is conditional CSS by browser but I'm interested to see if there is conditional CSS by OS. Here is my motivation:

I developed a website using custom fonts via CSS3. The font looks beautiful on all browsers running on Mac OSX but look horrendous on all browsers running on Windows. I know this is due to the fact that OSX and Windows renders fonts differently.

As a temporary solution to this problem, I want all users on Windows browsers to use an alternative CSS file, where the custom font will not be used-- and instead revert back to a system font like Helvetica.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Or if not, is there a way to make fonts look better on Windows? I tried

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

with no avail.

Comment: Custom fonts should look fine on Windows too. Which browser/OS are you particularly concerned about?

Comment: @Ben: Chrome on Windows. It looks **slightly** better on Windows Safari, but not much (And no where near as good as on OSX). Here's screenshot comparisons of Windows Chroms vs. Mac Chrome: http://cl.ly/image/0a382v31210L (and on Windows, that WITH -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;)

Comment: Does it get better if you set the font to a different _fixed_ px size? (I've had problems before with em size becoming decimal pixel values. e.g 13.3px)

Comment: @Ben: Everything is set to px and not em. I never was a fan of using ems.

Comment: Which font are you using? can you post the relevant css that load the font face and sets the styles for the area in your screenshot?

Comment: @font-face {
 font-family: DIN;
 src: url('/DINPro-Regular.otf');
        font-weight: 300;
}

*, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, {
font-family: "DIN", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a good [option](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/07/16/jquery-browser-and-os-detection-plugin/). It is a jquery based solution. Once you detect the os you can add the css like this: (got code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery))

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="os-windows.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: Option link is missing