# Angular JS: Load CSS and JS files dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am in the middle of developing a web app. I am using AngularJS for loading all the files dynamically into the UI.

I have an `index.html` file into which all the files will be loaded dynamically on-click or on-load.

```
//index.html
<signin button> <signup button> // etc.,
//on-clicking signin button a SignIn-page will load in the below div

<div id="bodyview"></div>
// end of index.html
```

Now my sign-in page looks somewhat like the below structure

```
    /*a div where my accordion menu will load when the 
     *below submit button is clicked*/

    <div id="menu"></div>

    //other sign-in-form stuff will follow on...

    //submit button at the end
    <submit button> //only on clicking the submit button the menu will be loaded
```

Now my problem is, though I'm able to load the accordion menu.html file, I'm not able to load the css and js files it is dependent on. I have researched on stackoverflow but none worked for me.

Can anybody please help in determining a way for loading the css and js dependencies using AngularJS

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just write a service to add CSS and JS files to the `<head>`

Here is a example service which is used to dynamically load CSS files.You can modify it easily to load JS files.

https://github.com/Yappli/angular-css-injector

Comment: can this be also used to inject JS files?

Comment: How we can add js files using it? e.g. controllers.

Comment: If I do this, the view is displayed before the CSS is loaded... (and that service you linked is deprecated)

Answer (score 6):

Currently I use angular-css: https://github.com/door3/angular-css
Imho, it's one of the best and most flexible solutions at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going by AngularJS way, i tried to load the files using JQuery. It worked for me.
[You can check this link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery)

Comment: and here I thought I wouldn't see an answer that went the "why not use jQuery?" route...

Comment: The OP was trying to load file using AngularJS. Adding library like JQuery just to load files is not a good solution. This can be done in plain javascript also as described [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript)

Comment: AngularJS includes jqLite, so an extra dependency may not be necessary: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$compile) {
    $("#my").append( $compile("<script src='my.js'>")($scope) );
});
```

Comment: You should not do DOM manipulation in controllers. That's one of the pitfalls when using angular

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery to do the hardwork like this

```
/** resolve will come inside your route .when() function **/
resolve: {
        theme: function ($route, $q) {
            changeCss($route, $q);
        }
    }

/** This will come just outside your route .when() function, make sure the following function shall be in scope of the route provider **/
    var changeCss = function ($route, $q) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        // Change the CSS as per the param received
        if ($route.current.params.css != undefined) {
            if ($route.current.params.css === ‘dark’) {
                loadCSS(“assets / css / dark.css”);
                defer.resolve();
            }
            if ($route.current.params.css === ‘light’) {
                loadCSS(“assets / css / light.css”);
                defer.resolve();
            } else {
                defer.resolve();
            }
        }
        return defer.promise;
    }
    var loadCSS = function (href) {
        var cssLink = $(“ < link rel = ’stylesheet’ type = ’text / css’ href = ’”+href + “‘ > ”);
        $(“head”).append(cssLink);
    };
```

I have used Promise because this will make sure to load the css before it shows/load the angularjs route/page.