# Dynamically load head content in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have 2 css files and i want to use any one of them conditionally. How can i load css files dynamically. I have tried the following solution.

In controller i have a variable

```
$scope.style1 = "resources/css/style_responsive.css";
```

in index.html

```
<link id="base-style-responsive" ng-href={{style1}} rel="stylesheet">
```

But i doesn't seems to load the files properly. Is there any way work around to load files dynamically. I shall be so much thankful. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change `$scope.style1` to `$rootScope.style1`.

Comment: Thanks for response : Got this "Error: $rootScope is not defined"

Comment: Ask for `$rootScope` in your controller's constructor.

Comment: @Shahzeb Are you sure it's okay to not put `{{style1}}` in double quotes?

Comment: @Words Like Jared : I removed the quotes but still not working.

Comment: Are you loading your styles above ng-view?

Answer (score 0):

This is really ugly but since it's kind of hard to do fiddles and whatnot for this sort of thing... this may be the best way to implement a solution without being in front of you.

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wa4Ea/

```
myApp.service('styleSheet', 
    function($compile, $rootScope) {
        var variableName = 'customStyleSheet';

        var element = angular.element("<link data-ng-href='{{" + variableName + "}}' rel='stylesheet' />");
        $compile(element)($rootScope);

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element[0]);

        return {
            set: function (href) {
                $rootScope[variableName] = href;
            }
        };
    }
);
```

I'm not sure what you're doing, exactly, but you get the idea.  Modify it to meet your needs.

(Anyway, stolen from:

[Angular JS: Load CSS and JS files dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695156/angular-js-load-css-and-js-files-dynamically)

You *could* try searching a little harder :P )