# AngularJS: Load CSS based on data retrieved from the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to load specific CSS file using AngularJS controller.

HTML code looks like

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="CPCplusLunchLink" ng-controller="mainController">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="js/lib/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angularjs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/events.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/events.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="css/{{ css }}.css">
```

app.js related part

```
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
              controller: 'EventsController'
    })
```

mainContorller

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){


    // set the default css
    $scope.css = 'style';

}]);
```

and controller where I have set value for the CSS

```
myApp.controller('EventsController', ['$scope','events','$rootScope', function($scope, events, $rootScope){

// set dedicated CSS
$rootScope.css = 'style2';

    events.then(function(data) {
        $scope.eventsList = data.evets;

        console.log($scope.eventsList);
    });

}]);
```

but I'm not able to change default CSS value based on loaded controller.

Any clue what I have missed?

Comment: Maybe try using ng-src. But I dont think u can load css like this.Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695156/angular-js-load-css-and-js-files-dynamically

Comment: @Vivz I have tried to follow http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/load-css-theme-dynamically-on-user-selection-in-angularjs122 and https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-angularjs-and-nghref-to-grab-css-dynamically

Comment: I just went through it and realized that you have to let angular know about the controller before you place the css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to let angular know about the dynamic CSS variable which is defined inside the controller. So you have to define the controller on HTML tag

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="EventsController">
```

Comment: yep, example just for that here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/load-css-theme-dynamically-on-user-selection-in-angularjs122

Comment: @viz CSS I want to change using EventsController only for that particular view (home page only) and have it set to default for other views

Comment: Do you have a main controller apart from the partial ones? Try setting the variable on $rootScope or on $scope.$parent

Comment: @Viz No, unfortunately I don't. I will check that option and report back.

Comment: OK. I think I need to user `$rootScope` in both controllers and then do `$rootScope.$apply();` in my `EventsController` to bind it