# Change Css 'href' by javascript by browser size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been trying to apply a javascript that will change the Css href if the browser window or device is a different size. I have scoured here and tested all of them with no results.
here is my code so far.
 AND YES I TRIED MEDIA QUERIES AND THEY DON'T WORK

media queries i tried to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)"      href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 899px)" href="css/medium.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" href="css/narrow.css" />
```

the css links:

```
<link   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wide.css" />
```

the entire javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >  
    function changeImage(a) {
        document.getElementById("img").src=a;
    }

    function adjustStyle(width) {
        width = parseInt(width);
        if (width < 701) {
            $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");
        } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
            $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
        } else {
           $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/wide.css"); 
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
        $(window).resize(function() {
            adjustStyle($(this).width());
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why not use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)? WAY easier than this.

Comment: [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

[CSS media queries for screen sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847755/css-media-queries-for-screen-sizes)

Comment: tried the media queries and they don't work

Comment: You might want to post the media queries you tried to use (yes, I read the comments and the YELLING IN THE QUESTION). Unless most of the web is hallucinating, they *do* work, and are exactly the right tool for this job.

Comment: So the thousands of websites that are using media queries today are just not working? What do you mean they don't work?  Of course they do.  You are doing something wrong.  Show us how you tried to use media queries.

Comment: I've used Media Queries on every single project I've been a part of for the last 2 years. They work. Must be a PEBKAC issue.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery  Also, do not be discouraged by the trolling above. Improve your question and hopefully someone will help :)

Comment: @user3541459 What browsers and versions are you trying to support? If you're also targeting older browsers that [don't support media queries](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), there are [polyfills available](http://html5please.com/#queries) to help.

Answer (score 0):

To react on screen sizes in JS you could [use `matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) with media queries.

```
var stylesheet = $("#size-stylesheet");

if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {

    stylesheet.attr("href", "css/narrow.css");

} else if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)").matches) {

    stylesheet.attr("href", "css/medium.css");

} else {

    stylesheet.attr("href", "css/wide.css"); 
}
```