# Accessing path in javascript (concrete5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, concrete5

I am building a template for concrete5. The problem I am facing is that I have to access the css path from a javascript file. The plugin which has to do this uses:

```
breakpoints: {
        'global': { range: '*', href: '/css/style.css', containers: 0, grid: { gutters: 0 } }
    }
```

The file I am trying to access is located at

```
domain.com/application/themes/test/css/style.css
```

and not at

```
domain.com/css/stlye.css
```

Kinda stuck with my beginner javascript skills at this point.
The console gives me the error 404 for the file. Makes sense since the style.css file is not located where I am searching it..

The js file is located at:

```
domain.com/application/themes/test/js/init.js
```

How can I access the style.css file?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?  It is not clear exactly what you want help with or how one would get the right info to construct an appropriate path.

Comment: Sry, made an edit. better?

Comment: Is `domain.com/application/themes/test` known in advance or do you have to get that from somewhere?

Comment: That is known in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using the path below should work.

```
  /application/themes/test/css/style.css
```

placing the / in front of the url will make the browser look in the main folder first.  That is why you were getting "domain.com/css/stlye.css" when you placed the url "/css/style.css" in your object.

So I would try the following changes to your object to see if it works:

```
 breakpoints: {
    'global': { range: '*', href: '/application/themes/test/css/style.css', containers: 0, grid: { gutters: 0 } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `domain.com/application/themes/test` is known in advance, then it appears that you can just do this in Javascript:

```
var path = "http://domain.com/application/themes/test" + breakpoints.global.href;
```

If you need to load that style file once you have the path, then you [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery) shows you how to do that (you construct a `<link>` tag with that path in it and add that to the `<head>` section.

```
var path = "http://domain.com/application/themes/test" + breakpoints.global.href;
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + path + '" type="text/css" />');
```