# How to specify external js and css for new window opened using window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open some content in new tab or new window. The code which I am trying is

```
var w = window.open();

$(w.document.head).html("<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>");

$(w.document.body).html(data);
```

where data represents the html contents that is to be placed on the new window.The problem is that when opening new window all content is appearing, but its styles are missing. While checking  tag in head shows undefined. How can I display the data in new window with proper styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the *** with your html code

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.write('<html><head><title>Test</title>');
w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">');
w.document.write('</head><body>');
w.document.write('<p>This is the new page.</p>');
w.document.write('</body></html>');
w.document.close();
```

Let me know if this is useful :)

Comment: Sorry ...it's not working.Brought me to same trouble

Comment: I have added another edit I'm sure this should wok so I'm not sure whats wrong if not Sorry

Answer (score -1):

If you're using html you can just set the target to blank which will open the link in a new window:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">This will open in a new window</a>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: that's not possible in this case because the data that is to be loaded in new page has to be taken from backend.It's not a simple link as u specified

Answer (score -1):

Unless the content of the new window must be created by the first window, on the client side, it is easier to use a page that is created by the server and named as a parameter under window.open() - like so:

```
window.open ('/popup-content.html');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score -1):

The following stackoverflow answer [Add css file with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery) describes how to add an external file using **append** to the **head** element.

So in your case, something like

```
$(w.document.head).append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'/>");
```

should work