# Call a new CSS file on button click - but keep existing styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, attr

I have a page with a couple CSS files.   I want to call a new CSS file (not present on page load) when a button is clicked.  I want the other CSS files to remain unchanged though.

This works - but, it seems to replace ALL the css files and ONLY pulls styles from the new one I call.  How can I keep the existing styles in place and only override what I'm targeting in this new file?

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('link').attr('href', 'foo.css');
    });
});
```

Comment: This question was answered many times on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery

Comment: Your code doesn't work because it's not doing what you think it should do.  You're REPLACING rather than adding.  The duplicate solution I (and others) have provided answers your DESIRED results.

Answer (score 2):

```
  function addStyles(url){
     $('<link href="'+url+'" rel="stylesheet"/>').appendTo('head');
  }

  $(function () {
      $('button').click(function () {
          addStyles('foo.css');
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are replacing attributes of link element(s) on your page. What you should do is creating new element and appending this newly created element to the page.

```
/*create new element */
var newLinkElement = $('<link>').attr('href', 'foo.css');
/*append to head*/
$('head').append($(newLinkElement));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append to the header

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" type="text/css" />');
```