# Adding a CSS node into unknown pages using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I add a `<link>` node into the `<head>` section of a page using jquery? And if the element already exists, it should not be added twice.

I need to add this CSS file because it pulls in additional styling for my search function. This [jquery highlighter](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) requires the `.highlight` class be added to the page, so highlights look yellow.

**Edit:** I could do this, but it does not check if the element has already been added.

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated, and it's not a requirement that the plugin requires anyway, use `<mark>` or `<span>`

Comment: Why the downvote? You don't understand the question or don't agree with the premise?

Comment: Why do you care if it's already been added or not? The browser is just going to ignore it in that case.

Comment: As per @Juhana's link to the question above, you could check for a duplicate (answer on the same question): http://stackoverflow.com/a/29356581/6240567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details are commented in the source of the live demo: <kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/5aLSp31lt8p2co03gfQa/)</kbd> and the Snippet below:

**SNIPPET**

```js
/* This script can be placed before the closing </body> tag as is or wrapped in a declared function then called. (ex. function init() {....}) */
// Reference the <head>
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
// This will find a `('link` element with a `[href` attribute with the value ending `$=` with `"style2.css"` `]')`
var style2 = document.querySelector('link[href$="style2.css"]');
// create a <link>
var link = document.createElement('link');
// Add a href attribute with the value of "style3.css" to the new <link>
link.href = 'style3.css';
// Add a rel attribute with the value of 'stylesheet'
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
// If <link href='style2.css'... already exists, then quit, else add the new <link> as the last child of the <head> 
var inject = (style2) ? false : head.appendChild(link);
return inject;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link hraf='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='style2.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    </head>
  <body>
    <p>Use devtools and find the &lt;head&gt;. You should see the following*:</p>
      <pre><code>
  &lt;head&gt;
    &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"&gt;
    &lt;!--link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css"--&gt;
    &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css"&gt;
  &lt;/head&gt;
       </code></pre>
       *The code displayed above is always green.
      <script src="init.js"></script><!--script wrapped in a declared function in an external js file-->
    <script>
      init(); //Call init() right before the body closing tag or place the whole script here without being wrapped in a declaritive function.
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

This script will run during load and isn't dependent on jQuery.

Comment: I intend to, I have never left an answer unedited, you should really inform a fellow user when there's been more than a few minutes after a post. At 8k rep you should give me the benefit of the doubt, sir.

Comment: @DavidThomas even though I explained that I would edit my answer (as I always do), you and your "friend" downvoted me. This leads me to believe that you really don't care if the details are here or elsewhere. Please do me a favor and **don't** undo your votes. I like numbers that are factors of 5 and 2, having a rep ending with a 9 bothered me.

Comment: Explaining that you will doesn't mean that you will. Now that you actually *have* edited your post - and drawn my attention to that update with a comment - I have, I'm afraid, reversed my vote. Hopefully that doesn't upset you (genuinely, I'm not trying to be combative).

Comment: "Explaining that you will doesn't mean that you will." I concede, sir. As a 159k member I should give you the benefit of the doubt as well. No harm no foul, you have a good evening, sir.