# Append css file by jquery but css file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `Jquery` code append both `Css` and `Js` file to create a banner-slider with Owlcarousel.

The jquery code had appended both into `html`. The function `.owlCarousel()` work fine but the css don't. In console, it only `GET` the `owl.carousel.js` file.

The one I found most like is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery) I already tried but count not get it working.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var u = document.createElement("link");
        u.type = "text/css";
        u.href = "https://myurl/OwlCarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
        $("#lookbookslider-2").append(u);

        var t = document.createElement("script");
        t.type = "text/javascript";
        t.src = "https://myurl/OwlCarousel/dist/owl.carousel.js";
        $("#lookbookslider-2").append(t);
        $.getScript("https://myurl/OwlCarousel/dist/owl.carousel.js");

  $("#lookbookslider-2").append("html here");

});
```

I dont have access to `html` file. I can only work with my js file. How can I make the css file working? Or I have to append all the style directly?

Comment: Your scripts seems just fine, maybe element with ID `lookbookslider-2` does not exist in the time script runs? Try appending to `$("body")` instead.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: In console no .

Comment: http://prntscr.com/os0mdu it look like this. It just doesnt receive the css file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding css file with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `rel` attribute from the `link` attribute. Also note that `type` is not needed. Try this:

```
var u = document.createElement("link");
u.rel = "stylesheet";
u.href = "https://myurl/OwlCarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
$("#lookbookslider-2").append(u);
```

However it's worth noting that this can be simplified if you use jQuery to create the `<link />` element, and also you should append the new stylesheet reference in to the `head`:

```
var $link = $('<link />', {
  rel: 'stylesheet',
  href: 'https://myurl/OwlCarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css'
}).appendTo('head');
```

Finally, note that appending stylesheets at runtime is a little bit of an anti-pattern. If you're trying to make the page more efficient, I'd suggest using bundling and minification of your CSS and JS, and then include all required references through HTML on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the link the `rel` attribute-:

```
 u.rel  = 'stylesheet';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://myurl/OwlCarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css" />');
});
```