# How to toggle between two css files using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, themes

I have 2 css files for light mode & dark mode of the website 
light.css & dark.css in the same directory.

```
<nav class="nav-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#intro"><i class="bx bx-home"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#button"><i class="bx bx-button"></i> <span>Toggle</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

I have already integrated the light mode css file in the HTML. How can I use the

`<li><a href="#button"><i class="bx bx-button"></i> <span>Toggle</span></a></li>`

toggle icon to switch to dark mode css file in my website ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also/2685661#:~:text=69-,Load%20external%20css%20file%20like%20scripts%20in,is%20compatible%20in%20ie%20also&text=%24(%22,appendTo(%22head%22)%3B

Comment: switch on what?click event?

Comment: or this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680657/adding-css-file-with-jquery/5680757

Comment: @Tawsif  I want to toggle between my lightmode & darkmode for my website when I click  using the toggle icon. I have created separate css files for both modes. Now I want to just click on the toggle icon so that my website becomes dark mode.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I want to toggle between my lightmode & darkmode for my website when I click using the toggle icon. I have created separate css files for both modes. Now I want to just click on the toggle icon so that my website becomes dark mode. I feel the following does not align well with my doubt .

Answer (score 0):

Add a specific id for the css link and change the value of the attribute href when trigger your selected button using javascript/jQuery.